# Semantics of moves of owned pointers

Tags: rust

[This article](http://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/03/09/which-pointer-should-i-use/) seems to imply the possibility that the use of the term "move" in the rust documentation doesn't mean copies, but transfer of ownership at compile time. See this quote specifically:

> The compiler enforces that there is only a single owner. Assigning the pointer to a new location transfers ownership (known as a move for short). Consider this program:

Is this correct? are ownership transfers/moves not actually copies at runtime, but only a compile time abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a move is still a copy (in the sense of `memcpy`) although not necessarily of the whole data structure. However, it has the compile-time semantics that you list. That is,

```
let a = ~[1,2,3];
let b = a; // copies one word (the pointer), "moves" the data.

let c = b.clone(); // copies the data too.
```

(Note that I've used `b.clone()` rather than `copy b`, because [Copy is being removed](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/7739), and replaced by `Clone`, which is more powerful/flexible.)

This copying behaviour is required to happen, because (many) variables in Rust are definite chunks of memory (just like those in C/C++), and if something has a certain value, that value has to be in the appropriate location memory; This means moves (which usually involve transferring data from one variable to another) have to actually perform a copy.

Comment: Okay, it totally makes sense that it needs to be that way. The pointers are all allocated to the stack, at least if they're not nested in a heap allocated enum, right?

Comment: Yes, any variable on the left-hand-side of a `let` is on the stack, including pointers like `let a = ~1`.

Comment: (That is, it is on the stack if it exists in memory at all: often variables can either be optimised away, or are placed entirely in registers.)